# ¿Por qué no funciona código de booteo en API >= 26?

Tags: java, android-studio

Tengo el siguiente código el cual hace que al prender el celular, la APP se abra automáticamente, funciona bien en android 7.0 (API < 26).

No logro que funcione en android >= 8.0 (API >= 26).

Gracias por las sugerencias

El código es el siguiente:

```
package com.isabel.kinder;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;


public class AutoArranque extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {

        Intent service = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        service.setFlags((Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
        context.startActivity(service);

    }

}

}
```

En el Manifest tengo lo siguiente:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

y

```
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".AutoArranque"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

En este caso cuando el inicio del dispositivo se realice completamente se llamaría `onReceive()` de tu `BroadcastReceiver` y se realizaría el Intent para abrir la Activity, por lo tanto tu código podría ser únicamente:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    //if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {

        Intent service = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        service.setFlags((Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
        context.startActivity(service);

    //}

}
```

Pero si en verdad deseas validar, puedes realizarlo de esta forma:

```
if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
    Intent service = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    service.setFlags((Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
    context.startActivity(service);
}
```

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys gracias por tu sugerencia, revise las dos opciones que me ofreces, tanto en android 9 como en android 10 y en ninguno de los 2 funciono. En android 7 funciona bien. El MainActivity funciona bien cuando lo abro directamente.